# Javascript/Jquery on event trigger <div class=>

Tags: javascript, element

I've got a text/html slideshow with Javascript however upon cycling of new text I also need the script to trigger the :hover class on the menu item corresponding to the content present in the slideshow.

For a visual example please see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkyMJ.png

I've uploaded the JS code to http://pastebin.com/Kp4a7VXP for viewing.

Would really appreciate your help on this guys! :)

Thanks so much!

Kind Regards,
Jake

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It may not make sense to try to mimic the hover state, so it may be better to have a css class such as `.active` added to the element you want the hover state for, and then include the css from the hover state in that class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a CSS like

```
.item{
    /* normal appearance */
}
```

and

```
.item:hover{
   /* appearance when mouse over */
}
```

but as far as I know, there's no way to trigger the pseudo class :hover via javascript. But you can use a standard class for this like (but for semantics I would name it like .currentSlide or .activeSlide)

```
.item:hover,
.item.hover{
    /* appearance when mouse over
       or selected */
}
```

and then you can add and remove that class using javascript for the current slide element, like:

```
currentSlideDiv.classList.add("hover");
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can use a function like this, and call `highlightCurrentSlideName(currentContentItem);` inside `NextClick()` and `PreviousClick()`

```
function highlightCurrentSlideName(slideIndex){

    var slideNameList = jQuery('.contentmenu a');
    jQuery(slideNameList).removeClass('current'); //unhighlight all slide names

    var currentSlide = slideNameList[slideIndex];      //select a slide name by a numeric index
    jQuery(currentSlide).addClass('current'); //highlight that element
}
```

and add a class on your CSS file, and style it whatever you want.

```
.contentmenu a.current{
    color: lightblue;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

PS: I'm not a jQuery programmer I always write pure javascript, just noticed you have it there already.

Comment: Hi There, Thanks so much for your fast reply. I'm a beginner to javascript I've got the script and page design uploaded so if you could hop over to http://buzzhosting.org/devv/ and tell me where to enter code, etc that would be fab. Of course I'll be happy to make a kind donation afterward :)

Comment: @Jake edited my answer with some further help, I don't tested it, but I hope it help you understand the concept.